# manipulating url path node js express js

Tags: node.js, express, url, path

I want to render a page but the problem is that i want to set the path like res.redirect() does but i want to add parameters(not in url). this is my important code:

```
           return res.render("auth/main-auth", {
              title: "Signup",
              oldInput: {
                email: "",
                password: password,
                confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
              }
            })
```

I tried:

```
         return res.render("auth/main-auth", {
              title: "Signup",
              oldInput: {
                email: "",
                password: password,
                confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
              },
              path: '/signup'
            })
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Hello friends you don't have need to write return. Please try this.

```
res.render("auth/main-auth", {
  title: "Signup",
  oldInput: {
    email: "",
    password: password,
    confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
  },
  path: '/signup'
})
```

Comment: Path wouldn't work because it is also just a parameter and has no extra tasks than the title for example.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has this problem here is the result.

You can add a middleware that handles the get request for /login for example:

```
  return res.render("auth/main-auth", {
    title: "Login",
    oldInput: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
    }
  })
```

and then when you want the render but also redirect you can just simply redirect to /login and then the middleware handels the get request and gives you the right website and the path is changed right:

```
res.redirect('/login')
```

and know the path is changed to /login so the middleware is triggerd you could say and renders you the right page.